# Flutter response data is not fetching on the first try but work on second try

Tags: flutter, dart, response, dio

I'm getting some error where my response data is not fetching on the first try and it gives me blank space in the screen but when I try to open the same page again, the screen displays what should appear on the screen not only blank screen. I've tried to print the response data but for the first try it returns empty list and for the second try it filled with the data. I need help for this bug. Here is my code

My list screen

```
class ArticleListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routename = '/article_list_screen';

  const ArticleListScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ArticleListScreen> createState() => _ArticleListScreenState();
}

class _ArticleListScreenState extends State<ArticleListScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  TabController? _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
      length: Provider.of<ArticleListProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .topics
          .length,
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<ArticleListProvider>(context, listen: false);
    print(
      provider.topics.map((topic) => Tab(text: topic.name)).toList(),
    );
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      // Add Your Code here.
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        provider.getTopics();
        provider.getArticles();
      });
    });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        preferredSize: Size(MySize.screenWidth(context), double.maxFinite),
        home: false,
        judul: 'Article',
        searchField: true,
        tabBar: true,
        controller: _tabController,
        tabs: provider.getListTopic(),
        searchTextBox: SearchTextBox(
          textEditingController: _searchController,
        ),
      ),
      body: Consumer<ArticleListProvider>(builder: (context, provider, _) {
        switch (provider.myState) {
          case MyState.loading:
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          case MyState.loaded:
            return DefaultTabController(
              length: provider.topics.length,
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                      child: Text(
                        provider.sortValue,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: MyColor.neutralMediumLow,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TabBarView(
                        controller: _tabController,
                        children: provider.topics.map((topic) {
                          final articles = provider.listArticles
                              .where((article) => article.topic == topic.name)
                              .toList();
                          return ArticleListPostWidget(articles: articles);
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          case MyState.failed:
            return const Center(
              child: Text('Failed to load data'),
            );
          default:
            return const Text('No Data Found');
        }
      }),
      floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        width: 130,
        child: FloatingButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              isScrollControlled: true,
              useRootNavigator: true,
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return CustomBottomSheetBuilder(
                  tinggi: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
                  isi: const [
                    BottomSheetContent(),
                  ],
                  header: true,
                  judul: 'Sort By',
                );
              },
            );
          },
          teks: 'Sort By',
          widget: const Icon(Icons.sort),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(
        currentIndex: 0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my provider

```
class ArticleListProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String searchString = '';
  MyState myState = MyState.initial;
  late SharedPreferences _loginData;
  List<TopicModel> topics = [];
  List<Tab> tabTopics = [];
  List<Articles> listArticles = [];
  final ArticleService _articleService = ArticleService();
  final Dio dio = Dio();

  void changeState(MyState state) {
    myState = state;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<Tab> getListTopic() {
    tabTopics = topics.map((topic) => Tab(text: topic.name)).toList();
    // notifyListeners();
    print(tabTopics);
    return tabTopics;
  }

  Articles? getArticleById(String articleId) {
    return listArticles.firstWhere(
      (article) => article.id == articleId,
    );
  }

  Future<void> getTopics() async {
    try {
      changeState(MyState.loading);

      topics = await _articleService.getAllTopic();

      changeState(MyState.loaded);
    } catch (e) {
      changeState(MyState.failed);
    }
  }

  Future<void> getArticles() async {
    try {
      changeState(MyState.loading);

      _loginData = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final token = _loginData.getString('token') ?? '';
      if (token.isEmpty) {
        changeState(MyState.loading);

        listArticles = await _articleService.getAllArticlesNoLogin();
        changeState(MyState.loaded);
        return;
      }

      listArticles = await _articleService.getAllArticles(token);

      changeState(MyState.loaded);
    } catch (e) {
      changeState(MyState.failed);
    }
  }
```

my service

```
class ArticleService extends InterceptorApi {
  late List<TopicModel> topics;
  late List<Articles> articles;



  Future<List<TopicModel>> getAllTopic() async {
    try {
      const String url = 'https://13.210.163.192:8080/topics'
      Response response = await dio.get(
        url,
      );
      topics = (response.data['data']['topics'] as List)
          .map((e) => TopicModel.fromJson(e))
          .toList();
      return topics;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<List<Articles>> getAllArticles(String token) async {
    try {
      const String url = 'https://13.210.163.192:8080/users/articles';
      Response response = await dio.get(
        url,
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          },
        ),
        // queryParameters: {
        //   'sortBy': '',
        // },
      );
      articles = (response.data['data']['articles'] as List)
          .map((e) => Articles.fromJson(e))
          .toList();
      return articles;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

All I want is the response data is getting fetch for the first time I run it, but I've tried many ways and it still does not work, help me please.

Comment: One thing I notice is that you create the tabController at a point where the topics are not loaded yet. Also the loading of the data inside the build method I wouldn't do. Then it will call it on every rebuild. That you would want in the initState